# How to make User Input (STDIN) to move left and right in PERL - Unix Env

Tags: perl, unix, stdin

i'm a newbie in PERL. Whenever i tried to move left or right to delete characters in terminal it shows "^[[D^[[C^[[C^[[D". Is there a way to make User Input (STDIN) to scroll left and right to delete the data in PERL ?

i am looking for user to use keyboard arrows for example, to edit or correct what has just been typed without deleting the last entered characters with backspace.

Example code: 
print  "What is your Fav Food?; $food= STDIN;

i want the readline to be flexible to delete the user entries.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to be a lot clearer here. Where does Perl fit into this? Are you using a program that is written in Perl? Are you writing a Perl program? What environment are you working in?

Comment: Dave, i am looking for user to use keyboard arrows for example, to edit or correct what has just been typed without deleting the last entered characters with backspace.

Answer (score 0):

**STDIN** is a LINE input operator. You can change your input until you hit enter.

You probably want one of these:
https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/perl/prog3/ch02_11.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you want is known as input line editing. For that, You can either user some terminal aware perl module for getting user Input ( https://metacpan.org/search?q=module%3ATerm%3A%3AReadline). Or run your perl script under  `rlwrap` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) command.